# Iterative limit of $\cos(\cos x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Hello I am struggling with a problem around the iterated cosine function. We have $f(x) = \cos(x)$, $F(x) = \cos(\cos(x))$.
Define $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty $ by $x_0$ = 0 and $x_{n+1} = F(x)$

I have proved that $F(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and maps onto itself. I also proved that it tends to a limit as it is bounded in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and shown that the limit $L=\cos(\cos(L))$ .
However we were given another sequence $y_n = \cos(x_n)$ and I proved that the limit of $y_n$ is $\cos(L)$ by continuity. But I am stuck on how to prove that $$L = \cos(L).$$
I have thought of saying that as $\cos(x_n)$ is decreasing $y_n \le x_n$ therefore $y_n$ is in the domain of $F(x)$ therefore $y_n$ must tend to $L$ but $y_n$ tends to $\cos(L)$ hence $L = \cos(L)$.
What would be the correct argument for such a proof?

Comment: $F(x) = \cos(\cos(x))$ maps $[0,\pi/2]$ *into* itself, not onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\cos(x)-x$. The function $g$ is strictly decreasing in $[0,\pi/2]$, because
$$g'(x)=-\sin(x)-1<0.$$
Since $g(0)=1>0$ and $g(\pi/2)=-\pi/2<0$, the equation $g=0$ has a unique root in $(0,\pi/2)$, say $t$.

Let $h(x)=\cos(\cos(x))-x$. The function $h$ is strictly decreasing in $[0,\pi/2]$, because
$$h'(x)=\sin(\cos(x))\sin(x)-1<0.$$
Since $h(0)=\cos(1)>0$ and $h(\pi/2)=1-\pi/2<0$, the equation $h=0$ has a unique root in $(0,\pi/2)$. Such root is again $t$:  $g(t)=0$ implies $\cos(t)=t$ and
$$h(t)=\cos(\cos(t))-t=\cos(t)-t=0.$$

Comment: How can we know that such a root holds for both h(x) and g(x)?

Comment: @Venzuz See the last two lines